# Odd Voting on some answers?

Tags: discussion

I am puzzled by the voting on this question:  [How to clean a sleeping bag ?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/how-to-clean-a-sleeping-bag)

No disrespect to Nate Eldredge, but LBell's answer appears better and more usable-in-real-life.

Am I completely off base on my conclusion?  If not, how do we end up with the better answer having less than half the score?

Answer (score 4):

I think the obvious difference is that Nate's answer was posted 3 days earlier - and no matter what we would like to happen, early answers will gain points faster if they look reasonable.

I don't know what the upvote rate was, and whether that answer got a few upvotes before LBell's was even posted, but even now, a new visitor may see the top upvoted answer and think, "Yes - that works" without even reading the 2nd placed one. I hope they would read further down, but they may not.

Comment: +1 within 6 hours of your answer being posted

Comment: heh - you did that deliberately :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the problem you discuss is handled by the user who asked the question accepting the best answer as correct, even if it doesn't have as many votes. I would hope the person who asked the question would read through each answer to find the best one, whether it had the votes or not.

This system runs into a problem with users that don't accept answers often. In that case you can stoop to leaving a comment in the question registering your preferred answer. Not sure if that is kosher but it is what I would do if I felt strongly about someone else's answer being undervalued.